# Slow serialization permormance in rails 4 with activemodel serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, active-model-serializers

Removed N+1 queries but it didn't help me. There are only 40 objects and it takes 15 seconds.

I quess there are so many `Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale)` and `Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale)` db calls that serializing works so slowly. How could I refactor that db calls?

```
 class ShopsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

    attributes :id, :title, :description, :audio_sizes, :stocks_count, :image_sizes, :audio_count, :country
    has_many :images, serializer: ShopImageSerializer
    has_many :products, serializer: ProductSerializer

    def image_sizes
      total = 0.0

      stocks = Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).includes(:images).where(city_id: object.id)
      stocks.each do |stock|
        sum = stock.images.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + item.image_size if item.image.present?} || 0
        total += sum
      end

      total.round(2)
    end

    def audio_sizes
      size = 0.0
      Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).map{|s| size += s.audio.size if s.audio.present?}
      Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).map{|d| size += d.audio.size if d.audio.present?}
      size
    end

    def stocks_count
      Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).count + Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).count
    end

    def audio_count
      count = 0
      Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).map do |s|
        if s.audio.present?
          count += 1
        end
      end

      Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id).map do |d|
        if d.audio.present?
          count += 1
        end
      end
      count
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rails caching instead of activemodel serializers caching solved my problem. [link](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/caching.md)

Comment: upvoted for linking to AMS docs.  Too bad OP doesn't reference if version is linked version, 0.10.6

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should move your calculations at the db level but I dont have time to write this for you. Otherwise you still have the N + 1 problem because for each object to serialize, you query stuff.

Anyway a win in your situation would be to at least do queries once, memoizing them like:

```
 class ShopsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

    attributes :id, :title, :description, :audio_sizes, :stocks_count, :image_sizes, :audio_count, :country
    has_many :images, serializer: ShopImageSerializer
    has_many :products, serializer: ProductSerializer

    def image_sizes
      total = 0.0

      stocks.each do |stock|
        sum = stock.images.inject(0){|sum, item| sum + item.image_size if item.image.present?} || 0
        total += sum
      end

      total.round(2)
    end

    def audio_sizes
      size = 0.0
      stocks.map{|s| size += s.audio.size if s.audio.present?}
      distributors.map{|d| size += d.audio.size if d.audio.present?}
      size
    end

    def stocks_count
      stocks.count + distributors.count
    end

    def audio_count
      count = 0
      stocks.map do |s|
        if s.audio.present?
          count += 1
        end
      end

      distributors.map do |d|
        if d.audio.present?
          count += 1
        end
      end
      count
    end

    private

    def stocks
      @stocks ||= Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).includes(:images).where(city_id: object.id)
    end

    def distributors
      @distributors||= Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version of AMS you're on, how you're using the serializer, or much about your ar models or association serializers..

You also don't say what you've tried, or what docs you've read, so it's hard to know your investment in solving it yourself vs. asking the internet to do the work for you. If that sounds harsh, sorry, it's just comes from experience handling open source issues.

That said, AMS itself won't do any db operations for you.  If you want to eager load anything, that's something you need to do in your app, which means reading rails docs on associations and querying

It is a common problem in asking tech questions to not give enough info. I recommend you take a look at https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html or https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/f5ec8ed9d4624afa6ede9b39d51d145b53b1f344/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-an-issue or https://github.com/norman/yourbugreportneedsmore.info/blob/master/index.html

Quoting the last one:

## Hello there!

You've been directed to this website because you submitted a bug report to
      an open source project, but you provided too little information for the
      developers to be able to help you. Does this look familiar?

> *Hi, I'm getting a weird error when I use <program>, do you know
>         what might be wrong?*

Debugging software is hard, even when you have the code in front of you.
      Now imagine, trying to debug software on somebody else's computer, without
      any access to the code, without knowing what operating system is on the
      computer, or even what version of your software is being used. Your only
      hint is that "there's a weird error" and you have 1 line out of a 50 line
      stack trace to work with. Sound impossible? That's because it is!

### So you want help?

If you want to actually get your problem solved, here is how you can
      submit a good bug report that a developer will actually respond to:

- Got a stack trace? Send the whole thing - or better yet, send a link to
          it pasted on [Gist](http://gist.github.com) or Pastie.
- Provide context, for example what version of Ruby or Python or COBOL or
          whatever you're using, as well as the code that causes the problem.
          Again, Gist and Pastie are your friends.
- Better yet, create a small program that reproduces the problem, and put
          it on [Github](http://github.com), or zip it and send it in
          an email.
- Even better yet, if you are able to, add a failing test case that
          demonstrates the problem you are having, and send it as a pull request
          or patch.

### Too much info?

If you only remember one thing, remember this: **reproducibility is
      key.** If I can't reproduce your problem, I can't fix it.

### Not enough info?

For a longer guide on proper bug reporting, please check
      [Simon Tatham's excellent article](/tatham/en.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember DRY? I would refactor

`Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).where(city_id: object.id)`

**to `Stock` model** and make it a scope or scopes. It could be useful for the future too.

It may be that Rails will cache it better then.

One point to speed up your query could be by adding index to `stocks.city_id` unless you have it already.

You could also check the performance by [joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins)

`joins(:images)` instead of `includes(:images)`

Comment: `joins(:images)` does not preload images, hence it will cause N+1 Query problem. `joins` and `includes` used for entirely different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For each of those 40 items you are querying `Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale).includes(:images)` once, `Stock.with_translations(I18n.locale)` twice and `Distributor.with_translations(I18n.locale)` one time.

This leads to at least 40*2 + 40*2 + 40 queries.

You clearly need a way to create association between `Shop` and `Stock`, `Distributor`, probably with `has_many :through`. But as you are trying to access count of items from `Stock` and `Distributor` across city  you can query them and pass them along with options in serializer, or you can memoize and run those queries once as suggested by @apneadiving.